# Weird behavior (bug) of inputCheckbox in the visualforce

Tags: visualforce

**inputCheckbox and commandLink/commandButton can't work together !!**

**Case 1:**

Try the codes.

The visualforce action in this one can't work.

```
    <apex:commandLink action="{!SelectTicket}" reRender="outputPanel">
         <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!ordsOptions[o]}"/>
        <apex:param name="selected" value="{!o.id}" assignTo="{!selected}"/>
    </apex:commandLink>
```

Without

```
value="{!ordsOptions[o]}"
```

in the inputCheckbox. The almost same code just works fine.

```
    <apex:commandLink action="{!SelectTicket}" reRender="outputPanel">
         <apex:inputCheckbox/>
        <apex:param name="selected" value="{!o.id}" assignTo="{!selected}"/>
    </apex:commandLink>
```

**Case 2:**

It doesn't fire the action at all when add the inputCheckbox in another column.

```
    <apex:dataTable border="4" value="{!ords}" var="o">
        <apex:column >
            <apex:commandLink action="{!SelectTicket}" reRender="outputPanel">
                <apex:inputCheckbox />
                <apex:param name="selected" value="{!o.id}" assignTo="{!selected}"/>
            </apex:commandLink>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column ><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!ordsOptions[o]}"/></apex:column>
        <apex:column ><apex:outputText value="{!ordsOptions[o]}"/></apex:column>
        <apex:column value="{!o.Id}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!o.Name}"/>
    </apex:dataTable>
```

It just works fine without inputCheckbox along with commandLink:

```
    <apex:dataTable border="4" value="{!ords}" var="o">
        <apex:column >
            <apex:commandLink action="{!SelectTicket}" reRender="outputPanel">
                <apex:inputCheckbox />
                <apex:param name="selected" value="{!o.id}" assignTo="{!selected}"/>
            </apex:commandLink>
        </apex:column>
        &lt;-- <apex:column ><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!ordsOptions[o]}"/></apex:column> --&gt;
        <apex:column ><apex:outputText value="{!ordsOptions[o]}"/></apex:column>
        <apex:column value="{!o.Id}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!o.Name}"/>
    </apex:dataTable>
```

**The whole codes**

vf:

```
<apex:page controller="SelectRadio" sidebar="false">
    <apex:outputPanel id="outputPanel">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:dataTable border="4" value="{!ords}" var="o">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:commandLink action="{!SelectTicket}" reRender="outputPanel">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox />
                    <apex:param name="selected" value="{!o.id}" assignTo="{!selected}"/>
                </apex:commandLink>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column ><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!ordsOptions[o]}"/></apex:column>
            <apex:column ><apex:outputText value="{!ordsOptions[o]}"/></apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!o.Id}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!o.Name}"/>
        </apex:dataTable>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!rSfdc}" value="按鍵"/>
    </apex:form>
    <hr/>
    <h1>Debug</h1>
        <p>ordsOptions = {!ordsOptions}</p>
        <p>ordsOptionName = {!ordsOptionName}</p>
        <p>selected = {!selected}</p>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

class:

```
public with sharing class SelectRadio {

    public List<String> vars {get;set;}
    public List<Custom_Object__c> ords {get; set;}
    public Map<Id,Boolean> ordsOptions {get; set;}
    public Map<Id,String> ordsOptionName {get; set;}
    public Id selected {get;set;}

    public SelectRadio(){
        ordsOptions = new Map<Id,Boolean>();
        ordsOptionName = new Map<Id,String>();
        ords = [ SELECT Id, Name FROM Custom_Object__c ORDER BY Name ];
        for (Custom_Object__c tmp : ords) {
            ordsOptions.put(tmp.Id, false);
            ordsOptionName.put(tmp.Id, tmp.Name);
        }
    }

    public pageReference SelectTicket() {
        for(Custom_Object__c tmp : ords) if(tmp.Id == selected) ordsOptions.put(tmp.Id, true); else ordsOptions.put(tmp.Id, false);
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference rSfdc() {
        PageReference rp = new PageReference('http://www.salesforce.com');
        rp.setRedirect(true);
        return rp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug at all. And, it has to be so.

It is all about the logic of OO programming.

Finally, I found myself the answer.

Check the answer here: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Strange-Bug-of-the-apex-inputCheckbox/m-p/631629/highlight/false#M65163

It can be used to replace the selectRadio, and pattern code is more flexible than apex:selectRadio. The sample pattern is easily to use with apex:dataTable and apex:repeat. That's the reason to write the code. Enjoy it with me if you like.